# Reflection PropertyInfo.GetValue from Collection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, collections, propertyinfo

I have problem with reflection, dynamic invoking objects and reading collection values.
In Referenced COM/Interop it would look like this:

```
ICollection collection = (ICollection)sth.getCollection("parameter");
SomeObject obj = (SomeObject)collection["id='1'"]; //DB WHERE condition
```

Unfortunetly i need to make it with reflection and dynamic invoking object. Getting collection is rather easy, but reading "obj" is different story. How should i wrote this?

```
object oICollection = sthGetCollectionMethod.Invoke(
    sthInstance, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null,
    new object[1] { "parameter" },
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
//and here is the problem:
//how to access object as array/hashtable collection?
object obj = tICollection.GetProperty("???").GetValue(oICollection, ???);
```

I should add that in object browser i see "this[v object]", but in `ICollection.GetMethods()` i'm getting property Item (`System.Object`) (which is invisible/not there in Object Browser)

Comment: This is a .NET question, not a C# question

Comment: Are you trying to get the value of invoking a method? Are you trying to get the value of the specified property?

Comment: I think you're trying to access the indexer for the object?

    this[string blah]

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried `get_Item` ?

```
object oICollection = sthGetCollectionMethod.Invoke(
    sthInstance, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null,
    new object[1] { "parameter" },
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

object obj = tICollection.GetMethod("get_Item").Invoke(
    oICollection, new object[] { "id='1'" } );
```

Comment: Ought to be close.  Or GetProperty("Item").